# Failing to return a string from a function

Tags: c, pointers

I cant get it to work. I build a string and cant to return it, I tried to tweak with pointers but it didnt work too. Details in the code:

```
char* replace(const char* sSource, unsigned int nSearch, unsigned int nReplace)
{
   char str[strlen(sSource)+1];

   \\filling str and putting '\0' at the end......

   return str;  // At this point str = "abgde3"  TRYING TO PRINT STR INSIDE THE FUNCTION WORKS !
}
```

```
int main()
{
    printf("%s", replace("A39a933Ab",93,314));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may not return a local array with automatic storage duration  because it will not be alive after exiting the function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow what's the solution then? Probably creating a pointer? but where?

Comment: If you do not want to change the passed string in place then you need to allocate dynamically a character array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Works now, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U have to return pointer, not an array. Like here:

```
char* replace(const char* sSource, unsigned int nSearch, unsigned int nReplace)
{
   char str[strlen(sSource)+1];

   return &str; //Added & to get pointer to variable
}
```

Also, u should not return pointer to local var, so allocate memory for one, and return it.

```
char* replace(const char* sSource, unsigned int nSearch, unsigned int nReplace)
{
   char * str = (char *)malloc(strlen(sSource)+1);

   return str;
}
```

You must to clean allocated memory by `free(pointerToArray)`